# Google web search API for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

As a newbie programmer, it would be a bit difficult to build my own scraper.

I'm building a rails app that utilizes Google Search Results. It's basically supposed to make a standard google web search, retrieve the results, reorganize/manipulate them without storing anything to a database.

I want to be able to send parameters/terms as a Google search query and have the results returned.

I've searched through GitHub without much luck.

**Are there any rails gems that let you easily do a standard Google search query? (I'm not asking about Google Custom Search, i'm asking about actually searching results from google.com)**

**If there aren't any gems, what's the best approach to do this while writing as little code as possible. Also, i'm not going to be making too many queries and would like to avoid paying for any API.**

*Forgive me if my question sounds a bit stupid. Thanks in advance for any useful answers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Katie, there is gem for your requirement.        https://github.com/visionmedia/google-search

```
gem install google-search
```

Comment: Thanks hun! Appreciate it! :)

Comment: Google deprecated their API so this no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

look for pictures for game.

.... controller code above

```
uri = URI('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images')
#use for web/text search http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web
params = { :v => '1.0', :q => @q, :rsz => 6, :start => @start, :imgsz => "xxlarge"}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
  parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(res.body)
  parsed_json["responseData"] ||= {}
  parsed_json["responseData"]["query"] = @q
  parsed_json["responseData"]["game_name"] = @game.name
  parsed_json["responseData"]["links"] = ["#{@game.name} picture",
                                          "#{@game.name} images",
                                          "#{@game.name} screenshot"]
else
  parsed_json = {'responseStatus' => 500} #error code
end

render json: parsed_json,
content_type: "text/html"
```

.....
and now we catch it on the front

Comment: I'm looking to search through standard web/text results on Google

Comment: I wrote a simple example, taking it as a basis we can achieve what you want. I'm sorry my english